# How can I run a command at boot?

Tags: command, debian, raspberry-pi, startup, boot

I'm trying to figure out how to run a command at boot, like I would type it into the console. I'm using Rasbian with my Raspberry Pi, but I think this question is the same for Debian in general. The command I'm trying to run is:

```
sudo screen mono server.exe
```

I tried the following solution, but since I just started with Linux, I'm not sure if this is correct.

```
 #! /bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/server

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          server
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Simple script to start a program at boot
# Description:       ..
### END INIT INFO

# If you want a command to always run, put it here
sudo screen mono server.exe    

exit 0
```

Comment: The command you're trying to run is really three separate commands; 1. "sudo" which runs the next command as the super user. 2. "screen" which is a terminal multiplexer, and then 3. "mono server.exe" which is a runtime calling an executable if we're judging by the file name. Hard to know why its not working without more information.

Answer (score 4):

**Simple**
Run `cd ~`

Then edit `.profile`
At the bottom, put whatever you would like.

Comment: It will actually run after the ssh login of the specific user account. It is not running at boot up.

Answer (score 3):

The simple and easy answer, you go to `/etc/rc.local` and add your commands.

Don’t forget, your script *must* end with "exit 0".

Answer (score 2):

This way has worked best for me on the Raspberry Pi:

```
cd /home/pi
cd .config
mkdir autostart
cd autostart
```

Set the file name to whatever you want as long as it has `.desktop` on the end:

```
nano screen_mono.desktop
```

Then write this in that file changing commands to suit your needs:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Screen_mono
Exec=sudo screen mono server.exe
StartupNotify=false
```

This is the only method that I have found to work on the Raspberry Pi (I start a [VNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) server every time it starts).

Comment: Yes, but mustn't `screen` be connected to a terminal?

Comment: `screen` may have to be started detached in order for this to work: `screen -dm &`. And preceded with `sleep 60` to let the system be in a state where the IRC client `irssi` can successfully be started and connect to an IRC channel.