# I can't start Debian

Tags: debian

I used [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16823361/how-can-i-run-a-command-at-boot#) (first answer) to start a command on boot and now only this program opens on boot and nothing more. I tried to edit this file in recovery mode, but when I exit root mode, the system starts in normal mode and again only this program starts.

Answer (score 0):

You should edit the file `.profile` *of the user that you were using when making this change*, since the answer you mentioned used the command `cd ~` (note: you are probably changing the `.profile` file of `root`, or forgetting to save the file after changing it).

For example, if the user name was `nipayl`, then you should start the computer in recovery mode and edit  the file `/home/nipayl/.profile` on the terminal and erase the changes you made (you could use `nano` to edit, such as: `nano /home/nipayl/.profile`). Then **save the file** when you're done and reboot. That should solve the problem (hopefully!).